# Is there a way to limit the performance data being recorded by AKS clusters?

Tags: azure-aks

I am using azure log analytics to store monitoring data from AKS clusters. 72% of the data stored is performance data. Is there a way to limit how often AKS reports performance data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point we do not provide a mechanism to change performance metric collection frequency. It is set to 1 minute and cannot be changed.

We were actually thinking about adding an option to make *more frequent* collection as was requested by some customers.

Given the number of objects (pods, containers, etc) running in the cluster collecting even a few perf metrics may generate noticeable amount of data... You need that data in order to figure out what is going on in case of a problem.

Curious: you say your perf data is 72% of total - how much is it in terms om Gb/day, do you now? Do you have any active applications running on the cluster generating tracing? What we see is that once you stand up a new cluster, perf data is "the king" of volume, but once you start ading active apps that trace, logs become more and more of a factor in telemetry data volume...

Comment: I stand very corrected. I was referencing an older report of our usage and didn't bother myself to query it myself. Our Perf data is only 800MB on a high day. Since implementing more of our services, ContainerLog is by far the lion's share at 89%.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Container Insights enabled on your AKS instance then you can check what the top contributors to the ingested volumes of data are.
Use these instructions provided by MS - [Determining the root cause of the data ingestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-cost#determining-the-root-cause-of-the-data-ingestion).

Also, it is now possible to control data collection parameters, like interval, namespaces.
Keep in mind this is in Preview and you need to enable manage identity on AKS before this will be available.

More on this here - [Enable cost optimization settings (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-cost-config?tabs=create-CLI).

[image]